# Accessing Bicommerce API from Bigcommerce Store (Front End)

Tags: api, frontend, bigcommerce

I am developing a website for my client using Big Commerce API. Now I have to implement a functionality which is, users will be able to access Product Options by multiple steps. For example, users will be able to Select one product option and then will press Next button then 2nd set of options will come and so on..

I would like to achieve this functionality by API. Is it possible to access the Store API from Front End ? If yes then how can I do that ?

Comment: did u accomplish any part of this I can help and may have some questions for you too

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at the API docs first:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/

But no this cannot be done via the API. This sounds more like a javascript thing, if anything. It'd just be best to work with product options as they are intended.